# how to build scl, example are old and rpmlint contradict the documentation?

Tags: redhat, rpm, rpm-spec, software-collections

I read the [official documentation](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/), some [examples on github](https://github.com/sclorg/scl-examples) and [on atomicorp](https://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/source/atomic-php52/php52.spec) . But I am still confused!

Should have to make 2 specs? One to build the tools and another one for a metapackage?

If yes why atomicscorp's spec file seem to be a mix of spec and the meta-spec files ?

Moreover with rpmlint 1.10 on metapackage seem to contracdict the documentation and examples. I have this error:

```
scl-runtime-package-without-%scl_files
SCL runtime package must contain %scl_files in %files section.
```

And [examples](https://github.com/sclorg/scl-examples/blob/master/scl-bar24/scl-bar24.spec) used  %scl_files statement into the runtime part (line 172)

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should have to make 2 specs? One to build the tools and another one for a metapackage?

YES.

- One for the metapackage
- One for each package, which will require the metapackage-build in the buildroot.